# how to fix the error: "invalid item 'Flutter for Android' in the dependencies list"

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea, plugins, flutter-dependencies

I am using:

- **IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2**, build `#IU-201.7846.76`
- **Flutter Plugin**, version `53.0.1`
- **Dart plugin**, version `201.7846.93`

I created a project with the command `flutter create --androidx <name_project>` by the terminal of above ide.
When I **build** or **run** the project I met problems with dependencies of Flutter or something else...

[image]
[image]

But I still not understand the problem and what caused that after I tried my best for researching on the internet. Although I run `flutter doctor` command and everything is "Ok" but still an error. Many thanks for the helping!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply remove the Module that has the error. somehow IntelliJ Added that as a module but that module shouldn't be there. click that 'sign_in_flutter_android' module and click the little minus button above

Comment: Well, that worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: This only works until the next build. It will be right back in no time.

Comment: I don't see `sing_in_flutter_android`. Any other ideas?